# Will the following features of typescript decorators get polyfilled in browsers that don't support ES5

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

In the [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) it warns that:

> NOTE  The Property Descriptor will be undefined if your script target is less than ES5.
>
> If the method decorator returns a value, it will be used as the Property Descriptor for the method.
>
> NOTE  The return value is ignored if your script target is less than ES5.

So, if you want to use the features of decorators described above, I'm unclear as to what this means for lower-end browsers that don't support the ES-5 builds.

#### Which of the two scenarios does the warning suggest is correct.

**a)** If you're using a version of Angular/TS that supports compiling to ES5 then you're fine. All browsers will work regardless of whether you're using these features

***or***

**b)** Even if your angular project does support compiling to ES5 then the slugs that are made for earlier browsers (e.g. main-es2015) won't support the features described above. i.e. be very careful about using them.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, TypeScript will not automatically polyfill for specific targets. You would have to provide those on your own.

Comment: "The Property Descriptor will be undefined" and "If the method decorator returns a value" , if you use either of these features your code just won't work for older browsers, you can still make good use of decorators without using either of those.

Comment: Also decorator stuff absolutely can't be polyfilled because it's overriding stuff like what `x.a = 4` does, there isn't anywhere to polyfill that for an older browser.

Comment: ^ correction: **descriptor** not decorator. decorator is replaced at compile time it's descriptors that can't be polyfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give any reassurance about angular, but I can provide some reassurance that decorators still work fine in older browsers.

A decorator as a function that gets called with the class / method as argument still works perfectly fine on older browsers. For instance if I had a decorator to simply `Object.freeze()` my class that is fine:

```
@Object.freeze
class Test {
}
Test.a = 5;
```

This code should correctly throw an error on any browser that [supports `Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze#Browser_compatibility) whether or not it supports property descriptors. (this is a pretty weak example because descriptors are older than freeze but the point remains.)

However accessor properties are [supported as long as `Object.defineProperty` is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility)

```
function nonWritable(target: any,propertyKey: string | symbol,descriptor?: PropertyDescriptor): any{
    return {
        ...descriptor,
        writable: false
    }
}

class Test {
    @nonWritable
    field = 10;
}

const x = new Test();
x.field = 11;
```

This will only throw the `Attempted to assign to readonly property.` error in browsers that support descriptors, an older browser will still call the descriptor but the third argument `descriptor` will be `undefined` and the decorator's return value (a new descriptor) is ignored.

This means that versions of angular that can compile to ES5 then those will definitely work since it means that the decorator definitely doesn't rely on descriptor behaviour.  Angular that compiles to newer versions aren't necessarily *guarenteed* to still work on older browsers but I'd doubt descriptors are the limiting factor for compatibility, the only thing that really isn't backward compatible is `getter/setter`s and those would correspond to a API difference so I'd **guess** you'd be safe on the decorator front.